# How can I put the radiobutton icon in the center of the MaterialRadioButton View?

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]

Is it possible to center radio buttons with no texts (MaterialRadioButton)? Is there a switch in XML for that?

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBo
        android:hint="Car Coordinate Latitude"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
        >
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:cursorVisible="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBo
        android:hint="Car Coordinate Longitude"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
        >
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:cursorVisible="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
    <com.google.android.material.radiobutton.MaterialRadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

As you see from the code, my button comes to the end and has no text (shall be a selector for the two previous fields (see picture)). I want the radio button to be in the center of the square, not aligned to the left of the text that doesn't exist...

RG

Answer (score 0):

A little bit latter but you can use spannable to put icon and/or text on radiobutton.text like is described [here](https://android--code.blogspot.com/2020/07/android-kotlin-radiobutton-with-image.html). Your radiobutton will looks like that:

[image]

```
//i've updated the code from above reference
fun setRadioImageText(
    radioButton: RadioButton,
    drawableId: Int,
    text: String
) {
    val ssb = SpannableStringBuilder("  $text")
    val img = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(resources, drawableId, null)!!
    img.mutate()
    img.setBounds(0, 0, img.intrinsicWidth, img.intrinsicHeight)
    val spanImg = ImageSpan(img, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE)
    ssb.setSpan(
        spanImg,
        0,
        1,
        Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
    )
    radioButton.setText(ssb, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE)
}
```

Now, we can use setRadioImageText method like code bellow:

```
val radioButton = RadioButton(this)
radioButton.id = <ID> //set id
setRadioImageText( // set text with img
    radioButton,//can be other type of view
    <R.resource.id>, //resource id of png, jpeg or vector, 
    <text> //the text to be appended after img
)
RadioGroup.addView(radioButton) //add radiobutton to RadioGroup
```